# Laravel's hasManyThrough using wrong key on join?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

I’m having some issues with Laravel's `hasManyThrough` relation (L5.2).

I have Users and Groups and, rather than a standard joining table or a custom pivot model, I'm using another Eloquent model called GroupMembership to link the two.  Here's the relevant portions of the classes:

```
class User extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function groupMemberships() {
        return $this->hasMany(GroupMembership::class);
    }
}


class GroupMembership extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'group_membership_id';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function group() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }
}


class Group extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $primaryKey = 'group_id';

    public function groupMemberships() {
        return $this->hasMany(GroupMembership::class);
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, GroupMembership::class,
            'group_id', 'user_id', 'group_id'
        );
    }
}
```

My problem is with the `$group->users()` relation, where I'm trying to get all the users in a group through the GroupMembership relation.  When I try and access that, the SQL that is generated is:

```
select `users`.*, `group_memberships`.`group_id` from `users` 
inner join `group_memberships`
    on `group_memberships`.`group_membership_id` = `users`.`user_id`
where `group_memberships`.`group_id` = '10'
and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
```

In that query, the inner join condition is wrong.  Instead of `group_memberships.group_membership_id`, it should really be `group_memberships.user_id`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388459/laravel-hasmanythrough-on-a-belongsto-relationship).  I don't want `hasManyThrough`. I just want `belongsToMany` specifying a custom join table:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_memberships');
}
```

You can also add `withPivot` to pull other variables from the joining model.

The only drawback here is that when using `$group->users`, each `$user->pivot` model will be the default Eloquent pivot model.  If I really wanted to access my custom model, I'd need to implement something like [this](https://softonsofa.com/laravel-custom-pivot-model-in-eloquent/).